# Does anyone by any chance happen to know anything about URL 404 page

Tags: url, http-status-code-404

Does anyone by any chance happen to know anything about URL 404 page Error resolutions
If so I appreciate your feedback
Here is an example below actually exact
Thanks again much appreciated!!

“Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request”

Comment: What does that even mena? 404 means the URL does not exist. What resolution do you expect? Either the URL is mistyped / wrong or - well - it does not exist or you have no permission to see it and even know there is a document there.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a `404 Not Found error` was encountered while trying to use an `ErrorDocument` to handle the request”

The error is actually two for the price of one.

1. A site visitor requested a resource that the web server can't find, typically because the resource does not exist.
2. The site administrator configured the web server to display a (user friendly) [custom error page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)   to display when such an error occurs with an apache httpd `ErrorDocument` directive.
   And apparently that page also does not exist.

That can have many different causes that are more easily resolved when the site/server administrator inspects the (error) logs of the web server, server configuration and/or site content.